# Hechsher on Trans Fat

Tags: kashrut-kosher, health-safety-shmira, hechsher-certification

[The National Academy of Sciences (...) has concluded there is no safe level of trans fat consumption. There is no adequate level, recommended daily amount or tolerable upper limit for trans fats.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_fat#Nutritional_guidelines)

*V'nishmartem meod l'nafshoseichem!* How can kashrus-organizations endorse percentages that [many governments have forbidden](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans_fat#Public_response_and_regulation)?

Comment: @ShmuelBrin That doesn't justify (implicit) endorsement.

Comment: Why do you interpret kashrus certification as a recommendation to consume the product?

Comment: @DoubleAA I don't, but as information that they consider this permitted to consume.

Comment: @NBZ  http://www.jpost.com/Jewish-World/Jewish-News/Kashrut-authority-approves-cigarettes-for-Passover-307188 there is no support for doing it, but if you are going to, at least let it be kosher

Comment: Evaluating claims in the realm of dietary science is not among the areas of expertise claimed by kashrut certification organizations. They also (generally) don't claim expertise in, and therefore don't certify companies for, matters of business ethics, even though these are also regulated by Halacha. We have other experts (scientists and our own doctors) for determining the health effects of trans fats and we have other means of determining which products contain how much trans fats (government-mandated labeling).

Comment: @NBZ Do they check that the company didn't steal the food? I don't know that any major kashrus organizations do that, yet it would make the food very prohibited to buy (CM 356:1).

Comment: @IsaacMoses I agree that none of those things are _usually_ areas of expertise claimed by the organizations, but that doesn't mean they couldn't be. I'd prefer the Hechsher to tell me I can buy it and eat it, not that I don't violate a prohibition of Maachalot Asurot. They're now doing only half the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since eating one unit of the item in question will not cause you to get sick there is no Issur. I am basing this on a reply I got from a Dayan when I asked him if it was permitted to provide a lighter to a smoker when requested.

Comment: Just like a diabetic doesn't make _bracha acharona_ on sugary foods if the large amount harms him. _Mashehu_ doesn't, and therefore requires a _bracha_.

Comment: What about the poskim who say that smoking is assur?

Comment: @NBZ I just heard your comment today in the name of Reb Elyashiv OB"M.